# Business math: how to say increasing faster and faster

Tags: terminology

I have to make a presentation to business directors and I want to explain that for a particular item, the function of cost in effort is beyond "linear growth".

Here's where it gets hairy. My function is

effort = $ax^b$

or said in English "Effort is $x$ to the power of a constant $b$ times a constant $a$". In this context we expect the constant $b$ to be around $1.2$, so effort will increase faster and faster, as you increase $x$. I know I cannot call this "exponential growth" because $x$ my variable is not in the exponent. So what is the correct way to describe this, what sits between "linear growth" and "exponential growth". Can I call this "polynomic growth"?? "polynomial growth"?? This sounds odd for a business context, and odd for an exponent of $1.2$...

**Clarification**: My $x$ gets up to several million, so the emphasis on the difference with linear growth is very real.

Comment: You could say "superlinear" growth.

Comment: I don't find it precise. "Superlinear" means "anything more than linear". A 2nd degree polynomial is superlinear, but also exponential is superlinear.

Comment: Perhaps a graph like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7By+%3D+x%2C+y+%3D+x%5E%281.2%29%7D%2C+x+from+0+to+10000000) will be more convincing in a presentation than merely finding the correct terminology.

Comment: In English it is called a *power function* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_function                    or otherwise a *power law* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a matrix multiplication algorithm that is about $x^{2.7}$ fast (where $x$ is the size of the input). We say that this algorithm solves the problem in polynomial time, although 2.7 is not an integer. So, I guess "polynomial growth" is ok in a mathematical context. I don't know about business...

Comment: You don't have to guess, it's perfectly ok if 2.7 isn't an integer because it's $\mathcal O(x^3)$, which is polynomial.

Comment: I agree. I'm from a computer science background and have had "polynomial is good" drilled into me. It's a bit of a shift in mindset to the point where an $x^{0.2}$ ratio in effort to linear is thought of as significant :)

Answer (score 2):

Technically $ax^{1.2}$ sits between $ax^1$ linear growth and $ax^2$ quadratic growth. Quadratic growth is a lot less painful than exponential growth. Depending on what you want to emphasise, I would say it's close to linear growth, or greater than linear growth (either could be the case depending on the context). If you plot a graph with the x-axis related to something meaningful to your business you can actually illustrate the difference. A couple of rough plots below to show the idea.

The first just plots both your function and $y=x$ on the same plot: you could add annotation to show the extra costs you're incurring as a result.

[image]

The second plots the ratio.

[image]